# Visual Studio Team Services / Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I use Visual Studio 2013 on my local machine to connect to my Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) account for the source code repository. Having that said, is there a feature in the VSTS and/or Azure which if used, will eliminate the need of having Visual Studio on our local machine. Azure says that build, test and deploy. So, I am wondering if build includes construct as well.

Comment: You can use things like the Monaco editor, but personally, I think you'll find developing locally with the desktop IDE is the most robust choice.

Comment: "build" in that context is more around "build automation", not coding...

Comment: What type of project are you developing? If VS is your IDE for your platform, you will have to stick with it. As DanielG says, there is Monoca, but that's not a full editor.

Comment: Thank you Guys. We work on various projects, ASP.NET, MVC, Windows Forms. When I visited this link http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx. It mentions that Visual Studio Online Professional can be used for debugging and has IDE. So this makes me wonder if VS is available in Azure/Cloud.

Comment: Visual Studio Online Professional is a level/SKU that includes the basic capabilities of Visual Studio Online in addition to a "monthly rental" of the Visual Studio Professional IDE that installs on your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MSDN account comes with $150 of clouds time. You can spin up a VM with Visual Studio pre-installed from a template in only a few minutes. This would allow you to remote to a VM with VS rather than having to install it locally.

Comment: Visual Studio Online Professional - Does this come with feature to code as well ? or it is that I still need the Visual Studio on my local machine, but I can use Visual Studio Online for other features.

Comment: The Pro VSO SKU comes with Visual Studio. But yes, you need VS installed to code.